# How can one use Swift's Decodable to parse an arbitrary JSON string where you only know or care about a few fields?

Tags: ios, json, swift

The new Swift "Decoder" class sounds like a great way to parse JSON data, but all of the examples I've found use a well-known, well-defined 'struct' to do so.

In my case I'm querying an arbitrary website that returns a HUGE JSON string and I only care about a few of the (deeply nested) fields, so I don't want to take all that time to define a 'struct' to get at them.

Is it even possible to do this with "Decoder"?  And if so, how does one go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question seems to be based on a misapprehension about how Decodable works. As a convenience, Decodable is willing to do some automatic code generation behind the scenes so that you *can* define a struct or nest of structs and just decode the entirety of the JSON. But you are not *required* to take advantage of that in order to decode JSON.

- There is no need to define struct properties for "fields" you don't care about. If a JSON dictionary contains 100 keys and your corresponding struct contains just one property, no problem; that key will be fetched, and no others.
- With regard to the "deeply nested" part, it should not take you much time to write simple nested structs that perform the dive to reach the dictionary you really care about. But if you don't want to do even that, you could write an implementation of `init(from:)` that dives down and fetches out the desired values.

In other words, if you think of Decodable as consisting *primarily* of your implementation of `init(from:)`, and learn to write the code that it needs, you will see that this JSON can be parsed in a few quick simple lines of code.

As an example, here's a JSON sketch of a deeply nested piece of information with a bunch of extra information at every level that we want to ignore:

```
{
  "ignore": true,
  "outer1": {
    "ignore": true,
    "outer2": {
      "ignore": true,
      "outer3": {
        "name": "matt",
        "ignore": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I'd like to do is define a very simple struct Person that consists solely of the deeply nested `name`:

```
struct Person : Decodable {
    let name : String
}
```

I can do that! To do so, I implement Decodable myself, supplying a "hoover" CodingKey adopter struct and an implementation of `init(from:)`, like this (this may look like a lot of work, but it isn't, because the AnyCodingKey implementation is boilerplate, copied and pasted from [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7498?focusedCommentId=34892&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-34892), and the `init(coder:)` implementation is just a few lines of code that were easy to write):

```
    struct Person : Decodable {
        let name : String
        struct AnyCodingKey : CodingKey {
            var stringValue: String
            var intValue: Int?
            init(_ codingKey: CodingKey) {
                self.stringValue = codingKey.stringValue
                self.intValue = codingKey.intValue
            }
            init(stringValue: String) {
                self.stringValue = stringValue
                self.intValue = nil
            }
            init(intValue: Int) {
                self.stringValue = String(intValue)
                self.intValue = intValue
            }
        }
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            var con = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyCodingKey.self)
            con = try! con.nestedContainer(keyedBy: AnyCodingKey.self, forKey: AnyCodingKey(stringValue:"outer1"))
            con = try! con.nestedContainer(keyedBy: AnyCodingKey.self, forKey: AnyCodingKey(stringValue:"outer2"))
            con = try! con.nestedContainer(keyedBy: AnyCodingKey.self, forKey: AnyCodingKey(stringValue:"outer3"))
            let name = try! con.decode(String.self, forKey: AnyCodingKey(stringValue:"name"))
            self.name = name
        }
    }
```

When I want to dive into the JSON and grab the `name` information, it's trivial:

```
let person = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: json)
```

The result is a Person object with `name` value `"matt"`. Note that I didn't have to add any of the `ignore` keys and I didn't need to make a nest of structs.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can achieve this but with both `JSonSerialization` & `Decodable` , you have to serialize the json until reach the desired content then decode it ,but instead I recommend to  create structs for root keys only then decode , think of it as it's a path from top to bottom don't decode a key that isn't in the path of your desired content