# Decode nested JSON child with Decodable

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I have some JSON (from last.fm) that looks like this:

```
{
    "results": {
        "opensearch:Query": {
            "#text": "",
            "role": "request",
            "searchTerms": "believe",
            "startPage": "1"
        },
        "opensearch:totalResults": "119100",
        "opensearch:startIndex": "0",
        "opensearch:itemsPerPage": "50",
        "albummatches": {
            // It's this array that I actually want:
            "album": [
                {
                    "name": "Believe",
                    "artist": "Disturbed",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Disturbed/Believe",
                    "image": [
                        {
                            "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/bca3b80481394e25b03f4fc77c338897.png",
                            "size": "small"
                        },
                        // There are more here.
                        …
                    ]
                },
                // There are more here.
                …
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to decode the nested array `album`, which is three levels deep. I can happily implement a `Decodable` struct for this, which will be something like this (untested, but builds):

```
struct Album: Decodable {
  let name: String
  let artist: String
  let url: URL
  let image: [Image]

  struct Image: Decodable {
    let url: URL
    let size: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case url = "#text"
      case size
    }
  }
}
```

However, is there a nice way to reach in to the JSON and start parsing at the `album` array?

I could implement `ResponseContainer`, `Results` and `AlbumMatches` structs like this to achieve this:

```
struct ResponseContainer: Decodable {
   let results: Results
}

struct Results: Decodable {
    let albummatches: AlbumMatches
}

struct AlbumMatches: Decodable {
    let album: [Album]
}
```

…but this doesn't seem like a great approach when what I really want to do is something like:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let albums = try! decoder.decode(
  [Album].self, 
  for: jsonData, 
  // Made up path parameter to let me jump to a child.
  at: "results.albummatches.album"
)
```

I'd also like to avoid deserialising the JSON with `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: …, options: …)`, pulling out the specific piece and re-serialising this, and then using `JSONDecoder`, as this seems very wasteful, although it certainly will work.

Comment: You might want to look into this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50686176/2299040

Comment: I will recommend you this tool: https://app.quicktype.io/ . it will generate a similar structure to this this: https://pastebin.com/nnn0hbqu and then you can use:

`let lastFm = try JSONDecoder().decode(LastFm.self, from: jsonData);
let albumList = lastFm.results.albummatches.album
`